# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffffe6c

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Help...
I got this exception for two days .What I have done is just add a static String in global class, like this
`public static final String MONTH = "month";`
And Use it as this 
 `map.put(MONTH, month);`

Here is the Exception..

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffffe6c
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2094)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
  at com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseQuickAdapter.getItemView(BaseQuickAdapter.java:1470)
  at com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseQuickAdapter.createBaseViewHolder(BaseQuickAdapter.java:987)
  at com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseMultiItemQuickAdapter.onCreateDefViewHolder(BaseMultiItemQuickAdapter.java:49)
  at com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseQuickAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(BaseQuickAdapter.java:759)
  at com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseQuickAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(BaseQuickAdapter.java:68)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6367)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
  at com.doushi.library.widgets.canrefresh.CanRefreshLayout.childLayout(CanRefreshLayout.java:449)
  at com.doushi.library.widgets.canrefresh.CanRefreshLayout.onLayout(CanRefreshLayout.java:414)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
```

When I reinstall the app, It work. but after operation, it crash again.

I use mon

Comment: post the relevant code here

Comment: thanks !  I got it. The reason is , use the BaseQuickAdapter's API
getItemViewType without add the type. I find it with debug mode 
at com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseQuickAdapter.getItemView(BaseQuickAdapter.java:1470)